# HttpSessionBindingListener equivalent for reactive WebSession

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

What is or how to get notified when a `WebSession` has the equivalent of the `HttpSessionBindingListener valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event)` or  `valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event)` for reactive netty server.

Cant seem to find anything on it when digging through the docs or web searches.

Would show code, but none exists.

I would like to create a list of authenticated users so that another server can check the list for active users. I would like to maintain this list based off the above events so I can trigger those events by other things like when revoking tokens or whatever.